# Detect all 4 rotations of device in android

Tags: android

I have an activity which is in Portrait mode only.
Inside which I have an image, which I have to rotate in four directions according to the rotation of the device.

What I want is I want to detect the four orientations of the device So that I can rotate the image accordingly.

With the current API I could detect only LANDSCAPE and PORTRAIT.

I was using OrientationChanged Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OrientationEventListener. It gives rotation in degrees. You can clamp it to four orientations and rotate the image accordingly. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Display.getRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29) method to check the current orientation.

Call it like this:

```
WindowManager windowManager =  (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
int rotation = display.getRotation();
```

There are constants for all 4 orientations like `Surface.ROTATION_0` which are described in the link.